# Static web with PHP

Tags: php

Is there anyway to make a web static (like Jekyll) with PHP?
It would render yaml block on post file. I confused how to figured it out.

Comment: Why not just use Jekyll (since you can use it locally and don't need Ruby on your server)?

Comment: @Jordan I've still use Jekyll, and I want something different, static web with PHP engine.

Answer (score 6):

[Phrozn](http://www.phrozn.info/) looks like a static site generator similar to Jekyll but built in PHP. Hope it's helpful!

Comment: yeah, I found that some days ago and looks too complex. I want make a simple one. Any links?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, php can generate static websites.

You can use a functionality called Output Buffering, rendering your pages with PHP and then saving the output buffer to files.

Some early blogging systems used that, CakePHP and Lithium use output buffers to generate page caches.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

There's new face available on Github — [Sculpin.io](https://sculpin.io/)